# Big RDD versus Multiple small RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning, rdd

**Historic Data:**

1. I have multiple tables per activity that contains some historic information like GRPs and CPPs
2. I have multiple dimensions across which GRPs and CPPs is defined for each activity
   Dimensions- Geography, TimePeriod, Primary_Message
3. Each activity might contain a subset of these dimensions

**Example**

```
 Activity1 {Geography, TimePeriod, GRP, CPP}

 Activity2 {TimePeriod, GRP, CPP}

 Activity3 {Primary_Message, TimePeriod, GRP, CPP}
```

**Use Case:**

1. Sometimes I would like to view the data across Time periods (this
   dimension is available for all activities) for all activities
2. Sometimes I would like to view the data across geographies (this dimension is present in a few activities)

I have to design the RDDs such that all my use cases efficiently work.

At any given point in time, each job will cater to one single activity.

**I have two options -**

1. Create one RDD for each activity and parition it across dimensions in that table.
   Thus I will have as many RDDs as I have activities.
   For each job, I will access specific RDD and compute
2. Create a single RDD for all the activities and paritition it on some dimension
   For each job, I will access single big RDD and perform filter on that RDD for an activity and do computations

My question is which option is more efficient to design the RDDs given the use cases and assumptions.

TIA !

Comment: _"Sometimes I would like to view the data across Time periods for all activities"_ vs _"each job will cater to one single activity."_ Is that not a contradiction?

Comment: On the UI, data will be displayed for all the activities. In order to achieve this, we would run multiple jobs (one job per activity) and compute their values across time periods.

Comment: What have you tried so far? and what is not working? or should work better? These usecases are simple enough to quickly prototype and compare implementations. The Spark-shell is your friend: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Comment: I guess a design discussion is not a great fit for Stack Overflow. We will never have the full context, and will never be able to run the benchmarks for you. But in this case I think the answer is quite unambiguous, so I added it. (I think separate RDDs will undoubtedly be more efficient.)

Comment: Thanks Daniel Darabos for validating that multiple RDDs is a better choice than having a big single RDD.

Comment: @DanielDarabos what is the recommended forum for such design queries as you mentioned that Stack Overflow is not the best choice for that. Thanks!

Comment: The `user@spark.apache.org` mailing list may be better. At least nobody will downvote you there :). See http://spark.apache.org/community.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of a single RDD is that adding another activity type (Activity 4) would be little work. The advantage of separate RDDs is that when you only want to access one activity type, you do not have to go through the data for the other types.

As you say in a comment:

> On the UI, data will be displayed for all the activities. In order to achieve this, we would run multiple jobs (one job per activity) and compute their values across time periods.

If you have N activity types and M total records, you would go through M records to render the UI if you have separate RDDs. You would go through N×M records if you have a single RDD.

Comment: since addition of activity at run time would be very rare so multiple RDDs is the right choice in this case. Thanks!